# How to get content uri in the format of media uri like content://media/internal/audio/media/0 in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-storage

I wrote code to get uri of picked audio file from android device. But the uri is not in the exact format that I'm expecting. Please check the below code.

```
 val audioPicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
     contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
     onResult = { uri -> 
        /* Here I'm getting the uri as
           content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A1000035469 but I need uri like this content://media/internal/audio/media/0 
        */
     }
 )

 //I'm calling it as
 audioPicker.launch("audio/*")
```

I need this 
**content://media/internal/audio/media/0** 
instead of this
**content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A1000035469**

Comment: Which content provider delivers the uri depends on from how and where the user picks the file.

Comment: Why do you only want the 'media' uri?

Comment: It doesn't matter what Uri format you receive, you should treat them all exactly the same. If you think the format makes a difference, you are almost certainly doing the wrong thing with that Uri. Please include what you are doing with the Uri.

Comment: Android can only media uri as ringtone, that's I need it. If I use this uri (content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A1000035469) then the ringtone is not playing. If I use this one (content://media/internal/audio/media/0) then the ringtone is playing. That's why I'm asking.